# Max Inputs FMU?

Tags: python, opc-ua, fmi

I'm trying to generate an FMU functioning as an Interface between simulated components (e.g. PLC´s) and a OPC UA server. My question is, if I´m trying to use this FMU for example to simulate an EtherCAT connection between these two, is there a maximum of possible in- and outputs?

I have a Code that hands me the nodes from the OPC UA Server already, but that are already a few hundred...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FMU Specification 2.0.4](https://github.com/modelica/fmi-standard/releases/download/v2.0.4/FMI-Specification-2.0.4.pdf) section *2.2.7 Definition of Model Variables (ModelVariables)* and the [FMU Specification 3.0.1](https://fmi-standard.org/docs/3.0.1/) section *2.4.7.1. Static information* both have a diagrams claiming that model variables are indexed from 1...∞.

Therefore, to adhere to the standard, FMI implementers should support the maximum number of variables possible in their environment. Which is most likely the largest integer they can use.